# Equivalence in Taylor expansion without using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

I need help with this:  If $n \geq 2$, we say that $f$ has a Taylor expansion of order $n$, that is, $f$ is $C^{n+1}$ and for every $x$ in the domain of $f$ there exists an open ball $B(x)$ around $x$ such that if $y \in B(x)$ then

$$f(x)=f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)+\frac{f''(y)}{2!}(x-y)^2+\cdots + \frac{f^{(n)}(y)}{n!}(x-y)^n + R_n(x),$$ where $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to y} \frac{R_n(x)}{(x-y)^n} = 0$.

I would like to prove that $f$ has a Taylor expansion of order $n$ if and only if $f'$ has a Taylor expansion of order $n-1$.

I was actually trying to prove this fact without using the fundamental theorem of calculus but I couldn't, is there a way to prove it without using this theorem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. Consider $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ if $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$. $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. We have
$$
f(x)=R_1(x),\quad \lim_{x\to0}\frac{R_1(x)}{x}=0.
$$
But $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$, so that it does not have a Taylor expansion of order $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I edited because the function should be $C^{n+1}$ and I took $n$ greater than $2$ to avoid a trivial case.

Comment: If $f$ is $C^{n+1}$, then of course $f'$ is $C^n$. But if $f$ has a Taylor expansion of order $n$ around some point $y$, $f'$ may not have one of order $n-1$. Consider $x^{n+1}\sin(x^{-n})$.